# Many-to-many relationship on parent/child form is limiting data entry

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, many-to-many

I have an Access 2003 front-end that used to use an Access back-end without problem.  I recently switched the Access backend to instead use SQL Server 2005, but I haven't been able to figure out this last issue yet - any help would be appreciated.

I have two tables in a many-to-many relationship:

```
tblMembership <--> tblLinkPersonMembership <--> tblPerson
```

Primary key fields are membershipId and personId, and the link table contains both and nothing else.

The Access application has a form that uses `tblMembership` as recordsource.  It has a child form whose recordsource is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPerson INNER JOIN tblLinkPersonMembership 
    ON tblPerson.personId=tblLinkPersonMembership.personId;
```

This worked fine when using an Access (2003) database as a backend.  Now that the backend is SQL Server 2005, I can enter 2 person records on the subform, but when the third person record for a given membership tries to save, I get the following error:

```
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find a record in the table 
'tblPerson' with key matching field(s) 'tblLinkPersonMembership.personId'.
```

If I close the form, re-open it and return to that membership (which now has 2 people associated with it), I can then enter 2 more people (persons #3 and #4), but if I try to enter a 5th person, I get the same error.  I can close the form, re-open, and add 2 more, ad nauseum.

I'm a bit stumped, and what research I've done to-date hasn't found anything.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with having Access form and SQL open side-by-side. Since you can enter 2(?) records with no (?) issues, I would enter one record and look at the database (three tables) to see what kind of data gets there. Then, for second record. The main focus would be PKs/FKs. Also, I would put ALL key columns on the Access form (PKs, FKs) to see how they get filled.

Then Parent/Child forms relationship. With your "*SELECT ** ", you are getting TWO personId columns. As long as you are using ***tableName.personId***, you should be fine but it is also something worth checking. E.g. making sure you are not editing PK of ***tblPerson*** while you want to update FK in ***tblLinkPersonMembership***.